# Regex match and replace word delimited by certain characters

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need a little help with regex to match and replace

```
<comma|dash|fullstop|questionmark|exclamation mark|space|start-of-string>WORD<comma|dash|fullstop|space|end-of-string>
```

I need to find a specific WORD (case insensitive) which

is preceded by: comma or dash or fullstop or question mark or exclamation mark or space or start-of-string

and is followed by: comma or dash or fullstop or question mark or exclamation mark or space or end-of-string

test string:
MATCH me, yes please,MATCH me but dontMATCHme!MATCH me and of course MATCH, and finally MATCH

I want to REPLACE all matches with another string in PHP, so i possibly need to use preg_replace or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$input = "MATCH me, yes please,MATCH me but dontMATCHme!MATCH me and of course MATCH, and finally MATCH";

echo($input."<br/>");
$result = preg_replace("/
                      (?:^             # Match the start of the string
                      |(?<=[-,.?! ]))  # OR look if there is one of these chars before
                      match            # The searched word
                      (?=([-,.?! ]|$)) # look that one of those chars or the end of the line is following
                      /imx",           # Case independent, multiline and extended
                      "WORD", $input);
echo($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not doing exactly what you asked for, but possibly fulfills your actual requirements better (which I'm guessing to be "Replace `MATCH` with `WORD` only if `MATCH` is an entire word, and not part of a different word"):

```
$input = 'MATCH me, yes please,MATCH me but dontMATCHme!MATCH me and of course MATCH, and finally MATCH'
$result = preg_replace('/\bMATCH\b/i', "WORD", $input)
```

The `\b` are word boundary anchors that only match at the start or end of an alphanumeric word.

Result:

```
WORD me, yes please,WORD me but dontMATCHme!WORD me and of course WORD, and finally WORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation in PHP that will do the task you described. It will replace all words with "WORD".

```
<?php

$msg = "MATCH me, yes please,MATCH me but dontMATCHme!MATCH me and of course MATCH, and finally MATCH";

echo($msg."<br/><br/>");
$msg = preg_replace("/(\w)+/", "WORD", $msg);
echo($msg."<br/>");

?>
```

Comment: Yes, this definition of "word" (letters, numbers, and underscores) is ok with me. How could i replace a specific word using this approach?

Comment: I managed to solve this, i came up with this (Warning: i do not know how effective is this and i hadn't test it thoroughly):

eregi_replace('([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])'.$oldvalue.'([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])',"\\1".$newvalue."\\2",$string);

If anyone can transform this to preg_replace i would be gratefull... i posted that question here if anyone can help me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479185/transform-ereg-replace-to-preg-replace

(i post this as comment because SO won't let me self-answer for 5 hours)

Comment: I updated the example with working a working php webapp. Try it out and see if it does what you need. Also, I don't think your regex will work if the word is at the beginning or end of a line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sky Kelsey, this does what you described, but unfortunately i need to replace a specific word, not just all the words! Um-mm...about my regexp, you have right, it won't work if the word is in beginning of string neither will at the end... i'm still trying to solve this...

Comment: So maybe modify your question and specify what words you are looking for?