# Transform ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

can someone transform this ereg_replace expression to preg_replace?

```
$string = mb_ereg_replace('([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])'
                         .$oldvalue.'([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])',"\\1"  
                         .$newvalue."\\2",$string);
```

Basically it searches a string ($oldvalue) which is preceded by space or dash or fullstop or plus sign or parenthesis or brackets or question-mark or equal sign and is followed by one of these too and transforms it to (whatever was preceding)$newvalue(whatever was following).

I need to switch to preg_replace due to technical limitations, I hope someone can help!

Thank you!

Comment: You mean "can someone just do this for me" .. not exactly. Ask for help, yes. But where are you in this >

Comment: No sir, i asked for help. I would say thanks to any answer, and will be glad even if the answer is not complete. I respect the volunteer help. (excuse any bad english)

Comment: Fair enough. It's just the way it sounds on the screen.

Comment: I often use smilies to express better in written language :D but i believe smilies+regex are not a good combination...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])' 
                     .$oldvalue.'([ -\.,\+\?\(\)\$\[\];_=])',"$1"   
                     .$newvalue."$2",$string);
```

Done.