# How to create new binary columns in existing database using variables from another database?

Tags: r

In an earlier post Benjamin and raymkchow helped me create new binary variables using a custom function for labeling diagnoses.

[How to use custom function to create new binary variables within existing dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455495/how-to-use-custom-function-to-create-new-binary-variables-within-existing-datafr/41463255#41463255)

```
patient<-c("a","b","c")
diag_1<-c("8661", "2851","8651")
diag_2<-c("8651","8674","2866")
diag_3<-c("2430","3456","9089")

patient_db<-data_frame(patient,diag_1,diag_2,diag_3)

   patient  diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
1       a  8661   8651   2430
2       b  2851   8674   3456
3       c  8651   2866   9089
```

The function for creating the new binary variable is shown below:

```
 patient_db<-diagnosis_func(patient_db, "diag_1", "2851", "Anemia")
```

Which creates the following output:

```
  patient  diag_1 diag_2 diag_3  Anemia
1       a  8661   8651   2430      0
2       b  2851   8674   3456      1
3       c  8651   2866   9089      0
```

This time I'm trying to use a similar approach but instead of using a single diagnosis code ("2851") and name ("Anemia"), be able to read the codes and corresponding names from a small dataframe named ICD9_codes. For example:

```
code<-c("2851","7840","7245")
name<-c("anemia","fever","back pain")

ICD9_codes<-data_frame(code,name)

code     name
<chr>    <chr>
2851     anemia
7840     fever
7245     back pain
```

Runnig the function below using the the code and names colums from "ICD9_codes" dataframe column results in an error.

```
  patient_db<-diagnosis_func(patient_db, "diag_1",ICD9_codes$code, ICD9_codes$name)
```

Error:

```
 Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = value) : no such index at level 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your function in a loop for `n` number of times where `n` is the number of codes you have in your dataframe (`ICD9_codes`)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ICD9_codes)){
patient_db = diagnosis_func(patient_db, "diag_1",ICD9_codes$code[i], ICD9_codes$name[i])
}
```

Comment: Please explain what trying this will accomplish -- in other words, how this answers the question.

Comment: However, it would be nice to have the for loop inside the "diagnosis_func".